# How do I change the AWS RDS database name which is restored from snapshot?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, snapshot

I recently restored an AWS RDS database from a snapshot, and it has the same database name as the original one, which I need to change for consistency and management purposes. My research suggests that there is currently no direct way to rename an AWS RDS database.

One common workaround I found is creating a new database instance with the desired name and migrating the data, but I am looking for alternative approaches or potential solutions that might exist. I want to explore any possible methods or techniques that can help me rename an AWS RDS database without resorting to creating a new instance and migrating the data.

If there are any less conventional or niche methods or if any new AWS features have been released that could facilitate this, I would greatly appreciate any insights or guidance. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You should not have connection to the database that you plan to rename. In my example I am trying to rename test1 database to test2. I connected another database something called newdb to rename

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply trying change DB instance identifier ,you can simply click modify and the specify new name.

Comment: not the identifier, I am trying to change the name.

Comment: Did " ALTER DATABASE <old name> RENAME TO <new name>"  not work ?  I am sure I must be missing something

Comment: No, it didn't work.